# Disk is full after runing gparted?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, gparted

I have around a 150GB hard drive that I had fully allocated to Ubuntu 10.10. I fired up the gparted live cd and reduced it by 47GB for a small ntfs partition for Windows.

When it was completed, I rebooted and Ubuntu seemed to load up fine, however, I get the following error at the gdm login screen:

> The configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly. Please contact your computer administrator.

I also have noticed that it says I am using 103GB of 103GB on my Ubuntu partition. Before the resize, I was using about 40GB of space.

Why does it suddenly think I'm using 103GB?

Answer (score 1):

Backup whatever critical things you have on the drive, then run `fsck` for the Ubuntu file system. You are, indeed, using still the same amount, but `gparted` may have forgotten to update some things after it finished resizing — maybe `fsck` will.